# MySQL nested ANDs and several conditions

Tags: mysql, select, pdo

I have two table for a multiple choice questionnaire (each user answers a series of questions):

```
users (userID, name, email)

votes (voteID, userID, questionID, answerID)
```

Sample data (**users**):

```
0, Some Name, some@thing.com
1, Other Name, some@one.com
```

Sample data (**votes**):

```
0, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2, 2
2, 1, 3, 2
```

I would like select all users who has the correct answers.

I tried this (where I've hardcoded the answers in):

```
$sql = "SELECT users.userID, users.name, users.email FROM users
INNER JOIN votes ON (users.userID = votes.userID)
WHERE (votes.questionID = '1' AND votes.answerID = '1')
AND (votes.questionID = '2' AND votes.answerID = '2')
AND (votes.questionID = '3' AND votes.answerID = '2')
AND (votes.questionID = '4' AND votes.answerID = '3')
AND (votes.questionID = '5' AND votes.answerID = '1')
GROUP BY users.userID";
```

But this doesn't return anything.

I've also tried something like this (where I've also hardcoded the answers in):

```
$sql = "SELECT users.userID, users.name, users.email FROM users
INNER JOIN transfertipsvotes ON (users.userID = transfertipsvotes.userID)
WHERE (transfertipsvotes.questionID = '1' AND transfertipsvotes.answerID = '1') GROUP BY users.userID
UNION
SELECT users.userID, users.name, users.email FROM users
INNER JOIN transfertipsvotes ON (users.userID = transfertipsvotes.userID)
WHERE (transfertipsvotes.questionID = '2' AND transfertipsvotes.answerID = '2') GROUP BY users.userID
UNION
SELECT users.userID, users.name, users.email FROM users
INNER JOIN transfertipsvotes ON (users.userID = transfertipsvotes.userID)
WHERE (transfertipsvotes.questionID = '3' AND transfertipsvotes.answerID = '2') GROUP BY users.userID";
```

But this just returns all users with **one** correct answer.

How do I make the correct query to select all users with the correct answers?

Comment: which column show if the answer is correct or not? and how?

Comment: I'm printing out the users.userID, users.name and users.email.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it now you need to use an INNER JOIN for each question, so each inner join will look like this:

```
INNER JOIN votes AS q1 ON (users.userID = q1.userID) AND q1.questionID = '1' AND q1.answerID ='1'
```

Repeat this for each question and you can check it.

Comment: This could work for one or two inner joins, but if you reach three or more, it takes ages and eventually times out.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want users who have answered all questions correct. In that case you should use INTERSECT instead of UNION

But for this you are hitting the table as many times as your questions. Its better to use OR clause in where "((question1 and Answer1) or (question2 and Answer2))". and at last do a group based on userid and get count of correct answer and fetch only those members whose has all correct answer.

Comment: You are corrects about my intention - but it doesn't work with INTERSECT instead of UNION.

I would prefer your second suggestion, but I can't quite see how the query would look.

Comment: select * from users where userid in (select userid from qusetions where (qusetion1 and answer1) or (qusetion2 and answer2) or .. group by userid having count(qusetionid) = <count>)

Comment: Thanks for the try, Mani, but I couldn't get your query working - I re-wrote it with the correct tables, but still nothing.